# Changing the start page in MDriven

Tags: mdriven

I have understood that using the "Index view model" to display data is not the the preferred way to show data at start-up. I therefore hoped to execute a periodic action in Index to redirect to the correct start page. But I do not see how I do this in practice? Has anyone used "Index" as start page with good results or has any one managed to execute the redirect action?

Answer (score 0):

Since the index is rendered with MVC - it must have a client side timer to execute any periodic action. I do not think there is one added currently - I think there was at one point but the ambition to keep the MVC pages clean removed it.

Comment: OK. That explains it! So what is the preferred way in TK to set the start page? Using Index might be cumbersome as this page is shown to non-logged on users? I also want this page to be data bound "live".